# How to convert a decimal ticklabel to minute/second format in pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

How to convert change extra y tick style from decimal to format minute:second?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\plotcoef}[2]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=0.92\textwidth,
                height=0.35\textheight,  % size of the image
                grid = major,
                grid style = {dashed, gray!30},
                xmin = 10,   % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
                xmax = 150,  % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
                ymin = 0,   % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
                ymax = 25, % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
                %        filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/60}},
                extra x ticks = {#2},
                extra y ticks = {#1},
                extra tick style={% changes for all extra ticks
                    tick align=outside,
                    tick pos=left,
                },
                extra x tick style={% changes for extra x ticks
                    major tick length=1.3\baselineskip,
                    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
                    /pgf/number format/fixed,
                    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},
                    /pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}%               
                },
                extra y tick style={% changes for extra y ticks
                    major tick length=1.5em,
                    y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/60}\pgfmathresult},
                    tick label style={rotate=90}
                },
                axis background/.style = {fill=white},
                ylabel = {%
                    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
                        \centering      
                        Infiltration time\\%
                        (for 1 cm lowering)
                \end{minipage}},
                xlabel = {Infiltration coefficient($l/m^{2}\cdot\,dia$)},
                tick align = outside,]
                \draw[blue, dashed, thick](#2,0) -- (#2,#1); %vertical line
                \draw[blue, dashed, thick](0,#1) -- (#2,#1); %horizontal line
                \addplot[domain=0:150, red, thick] {490/x-2.5}; 
            \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
    \begin{figure}[htb!]\plotcoef{1.46666666666667}{123.529411764706}\caption{Test result - Cx-01}\label{fig:cx1}\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a special tick label format set by

```tex
                extra y tick style={% changes for extra y ticks
                    major tick length=1.5em,
                    % y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/60}\pgfmathresult},
                    tick label style={rotate=90},
                    yticklabel={%
                      \begingroup
                        \pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}%
                        \ifdim\tick pt>\pgfmathresult pt
                          \pgfmathresult:%
                          \pgfmathparse{(\tick-\pgfmathresult)*60}%
                          \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
                        \else
                          \pgfmathresult
                        \fi
                      \endgroup
                    },
                },
```

you can get

[image]

Full example

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\plotcoef}[2]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                width=0.92\textwidth,
                height=0.35\textheight,  % size of the image
                grid = major,
                grid style = {dashed, gray!30},
                xmin = 10,   % start the diagram at this x-coordinate
                xmax = 150,  % end   the diagram at this x-coordinate
                ymin = 0,   % start the diagram at this y-coordinate
                ymax = 25, % end   the diagram at this y-coordinate
                %        filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/60}},
                extra x ticks = {#2},
                extra y ticks = {#1},
                extra tick style={% changes for all extra ticks
                    tick align=outside,
                    tick pos=left,
                },
                extra x tick style={% changes for extra x ticks
                    major tick length=1.3\baselineskip,
                    /pgf/number format/precision=1,
                    /pgf/number format/fixed,
                    /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
                    /pgf/number format/1000 sep={.},
                    /pgf/number format/set decimal separator={,}
                },
                extra y tick style={% changes for extra y ticks
                    major tick length=1.5em,
                    % y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/60}\pgfmathresult},
                    tick label style={rotate=90},
                    yticklabel={%
                      \begingroup
                        \pgfmathparse{int(\tick)}%
                        \ifdim\tick pt>\pgfmathresult pt
                          \pgfmathresult:%
                          \pgfmathparse{(\tick-\pgfmathresult)*60}%
                          \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
                        \else
                          \pgfmathresult
                        \fi
                      \endgroup
                    },
                },
                axis background/.style = {fill=white},
                ylabel = {%
                    \begin{minipage}{6cm}
                        \centering      
                        Infiltration time\\%
                        (for 1 cm lowering)
                \end{minipage}},
                xlabel = {Infiltration coefficient($l/m^{2}\cdot\,dia$)},
                tick align = outside,
            ]
                \draw[blue, dashed, thick](#2,0) -- (#2,#1); %vertical line
                \draw[blue, dashed, thick](0,#1) -- (#2,#1); %horizontal line
                \addplot[domain=0:150, red, thick] {490/x-2.5}; 
            \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
    \begin{figure}[htb!]
      \plotcoef{1.46666666666667}{123.529411764706}
      \caption{Test result - Cx-01}\label{fig:cx1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```